# Jquery - Need to validate text field with selected words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to validate input text filed with below values , `"PO BOX", POBOX, "GPO BOX"` and `"GPOX"`

if someone enter those words into text box, alert them "We do not ship products to PO Box addresses".
and remove entire text.

I have build below,

> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').blur(function(){
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('PO
>   BOX'),
>     $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('POBOX'),
>         $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('GPO
>   BOX'),
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('GPOX'),
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('po
>   box'),
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('pobox'),
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('gpo
>   box'),
>
> $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val()
>   ==    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('gpox')
>                 {
>
> ```
>           alert('We do not ship products to PO Box addresses');
>           $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val('');
>           $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').focus();
>       }
>
>   });     });
> ```

but problem is it's only validating exact word,

I mean if add PO BOX 1145 and some other text, it wan't validate.

Comment: When I tested your example, it DID validate with PO BOX 1145.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regex. I'm not regex guru, but you just need to look for text which has 'PO' followed by 'BOX' somewhere in your string.

So, this should do the trick

```
var regex = new RegExp("PO");
var match = regex.exec($('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val());
if (match != null)
{
    alert('We do not ship products to PO Box addresses');
    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val('');
    $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').focus();
}
```

Comment: btw, you can chain things together in jQuery so you can do $('...').val('').focus()

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you compare the match result to the original value.
if you change your lines from:
$('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val() ==$('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('GPO BOX'),

to:

$('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1').val().match('GPO BOX'),

it will work fine.
offcourse you can use regex matching with grouping for a oneliner validation, but current will work

(-: Y.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a regular expression. that will work in your case.....

`var str="GPO 123";`

`var patt=/PO/g;`

`var result=patt.test(str);//returns true or false`

`document.write("Returned value: " +  result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can check for containment using the String.indexOf(...) function.

```
var input = $('#objCheckoutRegistration_PhysicalAddress_txtAddressLine1');
var inputValue = input.val().toUpperCase();

var poBoxIdentifiers = ['PO BOX', 'POBOX', 'GPOX'];

for(var i = 0; i < poBoxIdentifiers.length; i++) {
    if (inputValue.indexOf(poBoxIdentifiers[i]) !== -1) {
        alert('We don\'t ship to...');
        input.val('').focus();
    }
}
```